# Azure Drive vs Block Blob vs Table

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I couldn't decide the best approach to handle the following scenario via Azure storage.

- ~1500+ CSV files between ~1MB to ~500MB overall ~20GB data
- Each file uses exactly same model and each **model.toString()** is ~50 characters ~400byte
- Every business day, during 6 hours period, ~8000+ new rows comes per minute
- Based on property value, each row goes to the correct file
- Multiple instance writing is not necessary as long as multiple reading is supported even there is few seconds delay for snapshot period is OK.

I would like to use **Block Blob** but downloading ~400MB single file into the computer, just to add a single line and upload it back doesn't make sense and I couldn't find other way around.

There is a Drive option which uses **Page Blob** unfortunately it is not supported by SDKv2 and makes me nervous about possible discontinuation of the support

And final one is **Table** which looks OK other than reading few hundred thousands rows continuesly may become an issue

Basically, I prefer to write files when I retrieve the data immediately. But, if it does worth to give up, I can live with the single update at the end of the day which means ~300-1000 lines per file

What would be best approach to handle this scenario?

Comment: Just FYI: You can modify existing Block BLOBs and add new blocks to it without reuploading the full BLOB. Or at least the REST API supports this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179467.aspx.

Comment: I can't answer if this approach is sound because I'm not sure what is reading these files.  You mention continious reads.  What is reading them?  Are the consumers caching any of the data?

Comment: Thanks @MikeWo I will definetely look into that.  A worker roles reads them via SDK.  Caching is out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your above requirement, Azure Tables are the optimal option. With single Azure Storage account you get the following:

**Storage Transactions** – Up to 20,000 entities/messages/blobs per second

**Single Table Partition** – a table partition are all of the entities in a table with the same partition key value, and most tables have many partitions. The throughput target for a single partition is:

- Up to 20,000 entities per second
- Note, this is for a single partition, and not a single table. Therefore, a table with good partitioning, can process up to a few thousand requests per second (up to the storage account target 20,000).

**Tables** – use a more finely grained PartitionKey for the table in order to allow us to automatically spread the table partitions across more servers.

About reading "few hundred thousands rows" continuously, your main obstacle is storage level 20,000 transactions/sec however if you design your partition so granular to segment them on hundreds of servers, you could be able to read "hundred of thousands" in minutes.

Source:

1. [Windows Azure Storage Abstractions and their Scalability Targets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/05/10/windows-azure-storage-abstractions-and-their-scalability-targets.aspx)
2. [Windows Azure’s Flat Network Storage and 2012 Scalability Targets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/04/windows-azure-s-flat-network-storage-and-2012-scalability-targets.aspx)

Comment: With the article you link to for the 2012 scability targets the throughput is now up to 20,000 entities/messages/blobs per second per storage account and as single table partition the throughput is now up to 2,000 entities per second.  These are for storage accounts created after June 7th, 2012.  A good deal reaching these scale targets are based on fine tuning your partitions, multi-threading, etc.